# How to integrate Truecaller SDK in Android along with Firebase Phone Authentication?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I want to integrate both TrueCaller auth & Firebase Phone auth(for users who don't use Truecaller). The problem I am facing is that the Phone numbers authenticated by Truecaller won't appear in Firebase Auth, so I can't use their user ID in the Firebase database. I am looking for any workaround to support both types of authentication with the Firebase database.

I have already tried integrating the Truecaller and Firebase Phone auth and it works. The issue is using them together at the same time, and checking
`if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null)`  doesn't work in the case of TrueCaller.

I want to integrate in my [Upride](https://upride.in) site also.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No, no solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually create user in Firebase Auth through Admin SDK after successful login of Truecaller.